# Two possible solutions to the limit of a function?

Tags: calculus, limits

Consider the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} x\cot(x)$$

If I directly substitute every $x$ for 0 , I get this
$ 0 \cdot\cot(0) = 0 \cdot1 = 0$

However , if I simplify the function first , I get this:
$\lim_{x\to 0} x\cot(x)$
$=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$
$=\lim_{x\to 0}\cos(x) \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{\sin(x)}$
$=1$

So which one is correct?

Comment: how come $\cot 0 = 1$?? Your second approach is correct however with right answer $1$.

Comment: $\cot 0$ is undefined ($\cot=\cos/\sin$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Cot (0)=\frac{Cos (0)}{Sin (0)}=\frac{1}{0}$ which is undefined, so your first one is not a solution.